# Is there any reference (or probably web/online calculator) to figure the size for downspout pipe for a known flow rate

Tags: roof, pipe, drainage, gutters, downspout

The total flow rate of water collected by the gutter of my roof is known (50 L/minute). I need to figure the safe size for my downspout pipe for this roof.

1. What's the minimum diameter for the downspout pipe?
2. Is there any guidance or reference (or probably web/online calculator) to figure the size?

Comment: Have a look at engineering toolbox.com

Comment: https://www.guttersupply.com/resources/proper-gutter-downspout-sizing.html.